# How to use Redux to transfer a user selection to another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to use Redux to transfer an item(item,size and price) selection from a product list to a separate cart component. I managed to set up Redux in my environment but can't figure out how I can use it to get this data. This is my `app.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store';

import App from 'views/App';
import Home from 'views/Home';
import Webshop from 'views/webshop';
import Cart from 'views/webcart';



ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={ hashHistory }>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Route path='/' component={ App }>
                <IndexRoute component={ Home } />
                <Route path='about' component={ Webshop } />
                <Route path='Cart' component={ Cart } />
            </Route>
        </Provider> 
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app') // eslint-disable-line
);
```

I believe I have correctly wrapped my components in the Redux `Provider` tags that will link my Redux `store.js` that looks like :

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';


var initialState = {
  data: [],
  url: "/api/comments",
  pollInterval: 2000
}

const store = createStore(
  applyMiddleware(
    createLogger(),
    thunkMiddleware
  )
);
export default store;
```

The value I'm trying to pass is `cart` in my `webshop.js` file that looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import{ Connect } from 'react-redux';

import Shirt from './shirt.jpg';


export default class addCart extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {value: 'medium'}
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.change = this.change.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        console.log(this.state);
        let cart = {price:0,item:"userselection",size:this.state.value};
        console.log(cart);
    } 

    change(e){
        this.setState({value: e.target.value})
    }

    itemSelection(){
        let userOrder = {price:0,item:"",size:""};
        let userItem = "";
        if (userItem == "shirt1") {
           let itemPrice = 20.00;
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className='Webshop' id='Webshop'>
                <li id="Productlist">
                    <div className='Product'>
                      <img src={Shirt}></img>
                      <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="addit">Add to cart</button>
                      <select id="size" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                        <option value="large">Large</option>
                        <option value="x-large">X-large</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className='Product'>  
                      <img src={Shirt}></img>
                      <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="addit">Add to cart</button>
                      <select id="size" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                        <option value="large">Large</option>
                        <option value="x-large">X-large</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

How can I get this `cart` value made from the user's selection and pass it to another component in a separate file?

Comment: Can you post your actions and reducers as well?

Comment: Two solutions to fix this. You can either add `cart` to your local state and pass it as `prop` to the intended component. Or if you want it available in the Redux store, then you need to dispatch an action for that. 

Side note, both component need to be connected to the redux store with `connect` HOC(Higher Order Component) if you follow the later suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to pass the `cart` to another component(WebCart).

- if the WebCart is child Component pass as prop.
- if WebCart is a sibling component(most likely it is) you can do with redux

the general steps are:

1. Create an action, eg. ADD_TO_CART
2. Dispatch the action along with the cart content
3. Have a reducer which will "catch" that action and put it in the store.
4. connect the webCart container to the store using the `connect` from redux
5. use the mapStateToProps function
6. once the action is dispatched, the cartItem will be available in the props of the WebCart container.

and to be honest, your code really does nothing because everything looks like hard coded you need to read a little bit of redux and post more code

Comment: This is just what I needed to guide me..I was just kinda really lost..but thank you for taking the time to outline everything I would need to achieve what I want..